# Select from 3 tables with 2 foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, select, join

I have a table `service` which contains `<PK> id` and `<FK> plate_number`.

Then I have a table `vehicles`, which contains `<PK> plate_number` and other not important columns.

Next table is a binding table `part_fix` containing `<FK> service_id` and `<FK> part_id`.

Last one is `part` with columns `<PK> id`, `name`, `price`.

I am using Laravel query builder but thats not so important now, just in case someone knows how to use it, a solution in query builder would be better for me but simple postgresql query is just fine.

I want to `select` from table `service` where I want to show in a table `<PK> id`, `<PK> plate_number`, and using the binding table, I want to assign parts for each `service`. I have the binding table because there was many to many relationship (one repair/service can have many parts, and also one part can be used in many repairs in autoshop).

I hope I explained this good enough, if not please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like

```
Service::with(['vehicle','parts'])->find($serviceid);
```

with the relationships on your Service class defined something like

```
public function vehicle() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
}

public function parts() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Part::class, 'part_fix', 'part_id', 'service_id');
}
```

This should allow you to load what you are after

```
echo $service->vehicle->plate_number;
foreach($service->parts as $part) {
  echo $part->name
}
```

Comment: Just thought of this, you might not want to use plate_number as your primary key as, depending on jurisdiction, plate numbers can get reused on other cars.